# Mocking Sendgrid using Jest in __mocks__ folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have this code below for sendgrid in my `__mocks__` folder:

```
class MailService {}

const mail = jest.fn(
  () =>
    (MailService.prototype = {
      setApiKey: jest.fn(),
      send: jest.fn(),
    })
);

module.exports = mail;
module.exports.MailService = MailService;
module.exports.MailService.prototype.setApiKey = jest.fn();
```

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: mail_1.default.setApiKey is not a function

      18 |
    > 19 | MailService.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY as string);
```

What am I doing wrong in my mocks folder? I am using the `setApiKey` and `send` functions only.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. You don't need any of the class definitions.

It's simply:

```
module.exports = {
  setApiKey: jest.fn(() => jest.fn()),
  send: jest.fn(() => jest.fn()),
};
```